# Show that $\bigcap_{r>0}B(a,r)=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty B(a,\frac{1}{n})=\{a\}$

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-writing

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. Show that

$\bigcap_{r>0}B(a,r)=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty B(a,\frac{1}{n})=\{a\}$

where $B(a,r)$ is a ball with center in $a$ and radius $r$.

**My attempt:**
Set $0<r\leq 1/n$. We then have the ball $B(a,1/n) = \{ x \in M : d(a,x) < 1/n \}$. When $n\rightarrow\infty$, $1/n\rightarrow 0$ which means that $d(a,x)\rightarrow 0$. Since $d(a,x)\rightarrow 0$, then $a=x$. Therefore $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty B(a,\frac{1}{n})$ contains the closed ball $B(a,0)$, and so $\{a\}$ can be the only point in the intersection. 
So $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty B(a,\frac{1}{n})=\{a\}$.

Since $r\leq 1/n$, then $B(a,r)\subseteq B(a,\frac{1}{n})$, and so the same must be true for $\bigcap_{r>0}B(a,r)$.

**Please** comment on my proof and tell me if/how I should improve it.

**Please don't** give me your proof. I want to learn how to make my own proofs work, and simply giving me your perfect proof isn't going to teach me that, I'm afraid.

Thank you. I won't be checking for answers right away, so please feel free to take your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Set $0<r\leq 1/n$. We then have the ball $B(a,1/n) = \{ x \in M : d(a,x) < 1/n \}$. When $n\rightarrow\infty$, $1/n\rightarrow 0$ which means that $d(a,x)\rightarrow 0$.

This first sentence is confusing. It seems that you have chosen a **fixed** integer $n$, and then a **fixed** number $r$ that holds $0<r\leq 1/n$. But after, you do $n \rightarrow \infty$. This is not correct, because it would force $r$ to be equal to $0$, while you want to have $r>0$. This is contradictory.

Dou you want $r$ to be lower than $1/n$ for **ONE** integer $n$, or for **EVERY** integer $n$? If you want to have $r \leq 1/n$ for EVERY integer $n \geq 1$, this implies $r=0$ and therefore you can't have $r>0$...

> then $a=x$, for all $x\in M$

This result is wrong: it would mean that your metric space $M$ contains only one point $a$ ! And you found this wrong result because of your reasoning error in the previous sentence.

> the ball $B(a,0)$

Actually, an open ball with radius zero is the empty set: $B(a,0)= \emptyset$. So technically you're not wrong when you write the following:

> Therefore $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty B(a,\frac{1}{n})$ contains the ball $B(a,0)$

but it is absolutely useless because **every** set contains the empty set.

> and so $\{a\}$ can be the only point in the intersection.

regarding what I wrote just above, this conclusion is false.

> Since $r\leq 1/n$, then $B(a,r)\subseteq B(a,\frac{1}{n})$, and so the same must be true for $\bigcap_{r>0}B(a,r)$.

Same remark than before: here, you are basically writing that **EVERY** number $r>0$ is lower than $1/n$, which is obviously false.

Comment: Thanks. "an open ball with radius zero is the empty set". My book says that the diameter is 0 when the ball has exactly one element, the center. If the diameter is 0, so is the radius. Where is the issue? Is it in the word "open"?

Comment: Yes, because an open ball with radius 0 would be $\{x \in M : d(a,x) < 0\}$, and a distance cannot be $<0$. On the other hand, the **closed** ball of center $a$ and radius $0$ is indeed $\{ a \}$

Comment: Thanks. I took out the "open", it wasn't part of the original wording, so maybe it could mean either.

Comment: Actually the correct assertion is with **closed** balls. If you take the intersection of the **open** balls, it will obviously be $\emptyset$ and not $\{a\}$.

Comment: Thanks. That is strange though, I checked my book again and it consistently uses this notation for open balls. But then the exercise shouldn't make sense?

Comment: Excuse me, I said something wrong. Here is the proof: if $x \in \bigcap_{r>0} B(a,r)$, we have $d(a,x) < r $ for all $r>0$ which implies $x=a$, therefore $\bigcap_{r>0} B(a,r) \subset \{a\}$. The reverse is obvious. It is the same proof for the other one

Comment: Given that for every $n$, $d(a,a)=0<1/n$, then $a\in B(a,1/n)$ for every $n$, then $a$ must be in the intersection.

Comment: Alright thanks both of you! I will keep that in mind and start over.